# White space/ spaces in dynamic links

Tags: php, html

A small but annoying problem im sure is something simple. I using a while loop to get some tags from a DB it works fine but it seems to creat white spaces in the second tag on woulds.

the code im using to egt the tags and push the into a array

```
$tag_array = array();
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE blog_id='$bid' LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            $rtag = $row['tag'];
            $tag_array[] = '<a href="../blog/?tag='.$rtag.'" style="font-size:12px; color:#000">'.$rtag.'</a>';
            }   
            $tag_array = implode($tag_array);
```

its prints the $tag_array and prints

```
<a href="../blog/?tag=tag1" style="font-size:12px; color:#000">tag1</a><a href="../blog/?tag= tag2" style="font-size:12px; color:#000"> tag2</a><a href="../blog/?tag= tag3" style="font-size:12px; color:#000"> tag3</a>
```

notice the spaces in the href link and the tag itself.

Any idea thanks

Answer (score 3):

use `trim()` on the tag. See http://php.net/trim

Sounds like the data is stored with those spaces. You should remove them from your data, and remove them in the code that puts them in the DB to prevent it from continuing to happen.

Comment: In this case: `$rtag = trim($row['tag']);`

Comment: Specifically, I wonder if initially the tags were entered as a comma separated list as in `tag1, tag2, tag3` and the software putting the tags into the db just did a split on `','`

Comment: @DanielMartin - exactly. (Hmm, what am I doing wrong that it won't convert to your name...?)

Comment: I see now i think the tags are being inserted with the space. atm i am entering them like so `$tags = explode(',' , $_POST['tags']);
   foreach($tags as $key => $value)
   {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (blog_id, tag, date) 
  VALUES('$blogid','$value',now())") or die (mysql_error()); 
   }`  How can i remove the spaces before entering???

Comment: Use trim() on the tag before you insert it. And then switch to PDO or at least mysqli and use prepared statements before your site explodes.